# How do I play GIF from a url using GifImageView by droids on roids?

Tags: android, gif

I need to play a gif file from a URL. I am new to android and am using droids on roids library to achieve this.

I tried the following code :

```
gifImageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
Uri gifuri = Uri.parse(gifurl);
gifImageView.setImageURI(gifuri);
```

I wanted the gif to start but instead I see a blank screen/

Answer (score 0):

Everything looks like it would work correctly... Make sure that the phone you're testing your app on is online, and that the URL you are requesting is an image and nothing else. Also, you could try using the [Glide Library](https://bumptech.github.io/glide/) instead of Droids On Roids.